# Setting property to newly alloc'd object using accessor cause memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I just want confirmation on whether or not the following causes a memory leak.

.h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyObject *foo;
```

.m file

```
@synthesize foo;
...

self.foo = [[MyObject alloc] init];
```

`dealloc` is setup as

```
[foo release];
```

My understanding is that the implementation of the auto-generated accessor method looks like

```
-(void)setFoo:(MyObject *)newObject {
    if (foo != newObject) {
        [foo release];
        foo = [newObject retain];
    }
}
```

Walking through `self.foo = [[MyObject alloc] init];` now reads to me as, "allocated a new MyObject object whose retain count will be 1, pass it to `setFoo:`, foo will never be equal to myObject as it was newly allocated, so release the old value, increment the retain count of newObject making it **2** and assign it to foo"

dealloc releases foo therefore setting its retain count to **1**, which means this object is leaked?

To do this safely we should write our code like

```
self.foo = [[[MyObject alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Is my understanding correct?

**EDIT**

I realize this question is not really appropriate for SO, so feel free to point me to a better place to ask this type of question as well.

Comment: The subject of the question is quite appropriate for SO. However, it has also been asked many times. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617849/objective-c-memory-question A search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+property+memory will yield plenty of information for you.

Comment: Subject yes, the type of question though seems to be frowned upon. "your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”" http://stackoverflow.com/faq  I figured it was asked before and searched and reviewed a few questions but didn't come across one that hit the point directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 3):

you could do that.  Alternatively, since we know the setter automatically retains, we could do the following rather than autorelease:

```
foo=[[MyObject alloc] init];
```

Which you choose may be a matter of coding style.  If you are trying to get the hang of using self.foo, then by all means use your method for the sake of consistency and bug fixing.  If you are comfortable with using the dot syntax then use the latter.

Answer (score 3):

And another common pattern:

```
MyObject *newFoo = [[MyObject alloc] init];
self.foo = newFoo;
[newFoo release];
```