# do I need to allocate and init variables with retain properties?(iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

```
@interface Approval : NSObject 
{
    NSMutableArray *approvalValues;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *approvalValues;
```

If i do this, do I still need to call `approvalValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] in the init method? I was under the impression that I had to but it is causing a leak.  In the dealloc method I am releasing approvalValues

Comment: I just posted an answer, assuming something about your code. Please try to post it the next time, to make it easier for others to answer.

Comment: How is it causing a leak? What kind of errors are you getting for you to say that it is causing a leak? What else are you using/assigning `approveValues`? Your question is too vague to get a proper answer. And the answer to your question is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `alloc` and `init` `approvalValues`. The problem seems to be related to the fact that you are over-retaining your object.

Your code probably looks like this:

```
self.approvalValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

`alloc` will return an object with a `retainCount` of 1, and when using the `retain` setter it will get bumped to 2. In order to solve it, you might want to `autorelease` the object before assigning it, making a code that looks like this:

```
self.approvalValues = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

This will end up with an instance variable with a `retainCount` of only 1, so when you `dealloc` the object it won't leak.

Comment: Or, if in an initialiser where `self` is discouraged just `approvalValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; and this owning call is balanced by the `release` in `dealloc`

Comment: In my opinion it's good practice, when using properties, to call `release` in `dealloc` as opposed to `autorelease` like you've done it in 2

Comment: @domino You still need to `release` in `dealloc`. Using `self.property = alloc-init` without `autorelease` over-retains the object, which is bad. Both alloc-init and the property accessor retain the object, so you need the `autorelease` or use a temporary variable to alloc-init, then call the accessor, and then release it. In both cases, you own the object afterwards and therefore you will need to release it in dealloc.

Comment: @albertamg The property setter already calls `autorelease` so you dont need to call it again as part of the init if you are going to call release during `dealloc`.

Comment: @domino This statement `self.approvalValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` in particular and all statements like `self.retainOrCopyProperty = alloc-init` in general over-retain the object causing a leak and are **wrong**. Read my explanation in my previous comment or refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024579/setting-property-to-newly-allocd-object-using-accessor-cause-memory-leak) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617849/objective-c-memory-question).

Comment: The absolute retain count of an object is meaningless;  do not encourage it's use or consideration.

Comment: @bbum agreed, it made for an easier explanation to use an absolute number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you still need to alloc/init, however you only release in dealloc method.

Comment: so why is the leaks tool telling me that there is a leak?

Answer (score 0):

In the init method you will often access the ivar directly and initialize it like this:

```
approvalValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

In the dealloc you will need a matchin release like this:

```
[approvalValues release];
```

It is often recommended to access the ivars directly in the init and dealloc method to avoid any side effects caused by setters/getters.

Throughout your class you will want to use the <strike>KVC</strike> setters/getters or dot notation to set objects like this

```
// Dot notation
NSMutableArray *tmpApprovalValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.approvalValues = tmpApprovalValues;
[tmpApprovalValues release]; tmpApprovalValues = nil;

// Call to setters/getters
NSMutableArray *tmpApprovalValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self setApprovalValues:tmpApprovalValues];
[tmpApprovalValues release]; tmpApprovalValues = nil;
```

Corrected terminology thanks to @Yuji

Comment: That's strictly speaking not a KVC. It's just a call to setter/getter ... KVC is an access via `setValue:forKey:`  and `valueForKey:`.